# LIKE with case sensitive wildcards

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects AS O
WHERE O.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND O.name LIKE '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

This is supposed to find all objects within the database that have at least three consecutive capital characters, however it doesn't seem to work and I'm not really sure why. I've tried to list all characters explicitly instead of specifying range, but it didn't solve the problem.

Sample data:

```
name
---------
HTMLTable
HtmlTable
```

Desired output:

```
name
---------
HTMLTable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
LIKE '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin
```

Comment: This is much better. I assume that collation was the issue and it was interpreting ranges incorrectly?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas yes. `Latin1_General_CS_AS` still sorts letters alphabetically. So, in the Order `'AaBbCc...'` *Edit: Note that also, characters with accents would appear in here too.* Thus, in your `LIKE` expression, the only invalid character would have been `'z'`. The collation given to you here puts the letters in case order as well: `'ABCDE...abcde...'`, thus your `LIKE` works as you now want.

Answer (score 2):

The below code should work -

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects AS O
WHERE O.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND O.name LIKE '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Comment: Strangely, this works. I just wonder why the heck it didn't work out when I have explicitly listed those characters myself. Anyway, this is great!

Comment: My guess - the regular expression [A-Z] is not case sensitive, even when you are specifying the collation sequence

Comment: Collating with `Latin1_General_Bin` works great even on ranges as suggested by [t-clausen.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806969/t-clausen-dk)